# Cannot inject service into Spring test

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, jhipster

`financialReportService` is null in REST controller that denotes it fails to inject.

**Test:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SnapshotfindocApp.class)
public class FindocResourceIntTest {
@Inject
    private FinancialReportService financialReportService; 
@Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        FindocResource findocResource = new FindocResource();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(findocResource, "findocRepository", findocRepository);
        this.restFindocMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(findocResource)
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver)
            .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter).build();
    }


@Test
    @Transactional
    public void getFinancialRecords() throws Exception {

        // Get all the financial-reports
        restFindocMockMvc.perform(get("/api/financial-reports"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
        List<Findoc> finReports = financialReportService.getFinancialReports();
        for (Findoc fr : finReports) {
            assertThat(fr.getNo_months()).isBetween(12, 18);
            LocalDate documentTimeSpanLimit = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(18);
            assertThat(fr.getFinancial_date()).isAfterOrEqualTo(documentTimeSpanLimit);
        }
    }
```

**The service:**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class FinancialReportService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FinancialReportService.class);

    @Inject
    private FinancialReportDAO financialReportDAO;

    public List<Findoc> getFinancialReports(){
        return financialReportDAO.getFinancialReports();
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/financial-reports")
    @Timed
    public List<Findoc> getFinancialReports() {
        log.debug("REST request to get financial records");
        return financialReportService.getFinancialReports(); // financialReportService is null
    }
```

**Update:**

The application is generated by JHipster. Then the [new service](https://jhipster.github.io/creating-a-service/) and DAO files were added to enable custom database queries to H2.

Answer (score 1):

After `@Inject`ing the service, you also need to set the field in the `setup()` method.  Adding the below line should solve your problem

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(findocResource, "financialReportService", financialReportService);
```

On a separate note, the following part of the test looks weird.  You are fetching the financial reports twice.  This file is the FindocResourceIntTest, so I would remove any direct calls to `financialReportService`.

```
    // Get all the financial-reports
    restFindocMockMvc.perform(get("/api/financial-reports"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    List<Findoc> finReports = financialReportService.getFinancialReports();
```